# Error while executing an Uber/ Fat Jar for a wicket bootstrap application

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, wicket

The gradle bootJar task creates a fat / Uber jar for my wicket bootstrap application.

when i try to launch the application using command `java -jar app-all.jar` , i get to see an exception as below

*Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Entry BOOT-INF/lib/jquerypp-1.0.1.jar!/META-INF/resources/webjars/ not found in file:/C:/workspace/app-all.jar
at de.agilecoders.wicket.webjars.collectors.WebSphereClasspathAssetPathCollector.collect(WebSphereClasspathAssetPathCollector.java:38)
at de.agilecoders.wicket.webjars.collectors.AssetsMap.getAssetPaths(AssetsMap.java:145)
at de.agilecoders.wicket.webjars.collectors.AssetsMap.createFullPathIndex(AssetsMap.java:164)
at de.agilecoders.wicket.webjars.collectors.AssetsMap.(AssetsMap.java:46)
at de.agilecoders.wicket.webjars.util.WebJarAssetLocator.(WebJarAssetLocator.java:28)
at de.agilecoders.wicket.webjars.util.file.WebjarsResourceFinder.newFullPathProvider(WebjarsResourceFinder.java:46)
at de.agilecoders.wicket.webjars.util.file.WebjarsResourceFinder.(WebjarsResourceFinder.java:34)
at de.agilecoders.wicket.webjars.WicketWebjars.install(WicketWebjars.java:75)
at de.agilecoders.wicket.core.Bootstrap.install(Bootstrap.java:152)
at de.agilecoders.wicket.core.Bootstrap.access$000(Bootstrap.java:66)
at de.agilecoders.wicket.core.Bootstrap$Builder.install(Bootstrap.java:102)*

The reported jar **jquerypp-1.0.1.jar** exists within BOOT-INF/lib directory .

I think the error is more related to a missing/incorrect  configuration related to webjars .

I tried the below resource handler configuration as suggested in forums and that didnt help .

@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry
      .addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
      .addResourceLocations("/webjars/");
}
```

}

Let me know if i am missing any other configuration

Comment: Do you deploy on WebSphere ? WebSphereClasspathAssetPathCollector

Comment: No . It is a spring boot Uber Jar . I am executing in command prompt through "java -jar app.jar"  . WebsphereClasspathAssetPathCollector should be coming from wicket-bootstrap .

Additional note : I am using IBM JDK

Comment: I get the same error while using open JDK as well

Comment: It seems your application sets up `WebSphereWebjarsSettings`. Since you do not deploy on WebSphere you should use the default - `de.agilecoders.wicket.webjars.settings.WebjarsSettings`